# global name 'bigquery' is not defined

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I created a google dataflow job but I keep getting global name 'bigquery' not defined even though I already imported the variable needed.

This is my import list:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import logging
import ast
import json

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText, WriteToText 
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

And this is the class returning the error:

```
class CheckExistance(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table.replace(":", ".")

    def process(self, element):

        client = bigquery.Client()
        date = element['date'].split(" ")[0]

        query_job = client.query("""
        QUERY """ % (self.table, date))

        yield element
```

Do you guys know what could be causing this error?
Btw, I only get this error when deploying it to google's dataflow jobs, it runs fine locally.

**EDIT:**

I was able to fix my initial problem by changing the position of my import to be inside the function that needs the bigquery variable, like this:

```
class CheckExistance(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table.replace(":", ".")

    def process(self, element):
        from google.cloud import bigquery
        client = bigquery.Client()
        date = element['date'].split(" ")[0]

        query_job = client.query("""
        QUERY""" % (self.table, date))

        yield element
```

But now I'm getting a error saying that 'client' has no attribute query, even though my packages on the dataflow job are up to date and it runs without any problems locally.

Error Message:

> AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'query'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you need to enable BigQuery

Resources / Advanced Google Services / Enable BigQuery

Edit : check the comments to see troubleshooting, findings, and what worked.

Comment: It's already enabled, I was able to fix the initial error but now I'm getting a different one

Comment: @PedroDaumas Compare the version of bigquery locally with where deployed.

Comment: both are using the same version of packages

Comment: @PedroDaumas Is Python/BigQuery supported on dataflow?

Comment: As far as I know it is supported, but I can't find a document to confirm this.

Comment: @PedroDaumas Shouldn't you be using client = bigquery.Client(project='PROJECT_ID')?

From here https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/index.html

Comment: I tried adding this but it keeps giving me the same error

Comment: @PedroDaumas You replaced PROJECT_ID with your project id?

Comment: @PedroDaumas Does client.run_async_query or run_sync_query work?

Comment: run_sync_query() Worked!
Thank you very much

Comment: @PedroDaumas Right. So most likely that means the deployed location is using an older library version because I read that query replaced run_sync_query in v0.28 and older. Read here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration